# Sinatra app doesnt redirect to haml files

Tags: ruby, twitter, sinatra

This is the Sinatra code that I wrote. All gems exist, the ruby files compiles perfectly but when i go to localhost:4567/ the sinatra app doesnt run. It takes me to the 'Sinatra doesnt know this ditty' page. What mistake am i making here? Is it a syntax issue? I've posted the main ruby file's code here others are just haml files thats all.

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default)

require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'twitter'
require 'oauth'

class MyTweetWeek < Sinatra::Base
  set :haml, :format => :html5, :attr_wrapper => '"'
 enable :sessions, :static, :raise_errors
 set :public_dir, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public')

 get '/' do
   haml :index
 end

 get '/login' do
request_token = consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => ENV['OAUTH_CALLBACK'])

session[:request_token] = request_token.token
session[:request_token_secret] = request_token.secret

redirect request_token.authorize_url
 end

  get '/oauth_callback' do
request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(
  consumer,
  session[:request_token],
  session[:request_token_secret]
)

session[:request_token] = session[:request_token_secret] = nil

access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])

session[:access_token] = access_token.token
session[:access_secret] = access_token.secret

redirect '/resume'
 end

  get '/resume' do
redirect '/'  unless authenticated?
today = Date.today #get today's date
monday = today - today.cwday + 1 #calculate Monday
search = Twitter::Search.new

@screen_name = client.verify_credentials.screen_name
@number_of_tweets = 0
@number_of_mentions = 0

results = search.from(@screen_name)
                .since_date(monday)
                .no_retweets
                .per_page(100)
                .fetch

@number_of_tweets += results.size

while search.next_page?
  results = search.fetch_next_page
  @number_of_tweets += results.size
end

search.clear

results = search.q("@#{@screen_name.gsub('@', '')}")
                .since_date(monday)
                .no_retweets
                .per_page(100)
                .fetch

@number_of_mentions += results.size

while search.next_page?
  results = search.fetch_next_page
  @number_of_mentions += results.size
end

haml :resume
 end

 error Twitter::Error::Unauthorized do
    redirect '/'
    end

 not_found do
  haml :not_found
  end

 private

 def consumer
   @consumer ||= OAuth::Consumer.new(
    ENV['CONSUMER_KEY'],
    ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET'],
    :site => "https://api.twitter.com"
    )
 end

  def client
   Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = ENV['CONSUMER_KEY']
    config.consumer_secret = ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']
    config.oauth_token =  session[:access_token]
    config.oauth_token_secret = session[:access_secret]
    end

@client ||= Twitter::Client.new
end

 def authenticated?
  !session[:access_token].nil? && !session[:access_secret].nil?
    end
    end
```

Comment: How are you running this from the commandline? `ruby app.rb`? `rackup config.ru`?

Comment: ruby app.rb is how i'm running it from the commandline.

Comment: @iain, why did this happen?

Answer (score 1):

As you have a modular app do you need to require "sinatra/base" rather than "sinatra"? See [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra%3a%3aBase%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps)

Answer (score 0):

See [Serving a Modular App](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Serving%20a%20Modular%20Application) and add the line `run! if app_file == $0` at the end of the class. Also see DavB's answer.